# Natuite adding custom GL impact while creating a sales order via suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

How to add custom GL impact while creating a sales order via suitescript 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation
[Suite Answers](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/41481/kw/The%20Custom%20GL%20Lines%20plug-in%20does%20not%20currently%20support%20SuiteScript%202.0.%20Only%20SuiteScript%201.0%20is%20supported.)

> The Custom GL Lines plug-in does not currently support SuiteScript
> 2.0. Only SuiteScript 1.0 is supported.

The Plug-in is the only way how to generate customized GL impact lines.